# R Shiny: change download button image

Tags: css, r, shiny, download, widget

I am attempting to the customize the default download button icon using a custom png image. I have written the following UI downloadbutton function that works and placed the intended image - icons8-downloads-folder-48.png - into to my www folder. I am quite new to Shiny and CSS, and I'm struggling to integrate the image into the Shinny code. Specifying the image in the icon argument does not work. Is there a simple solution? What I'm trying to do strikes me as very simple.

```
dwnldButtonUI <- function(id){ns <- NS(id)
tagList(
  dropdownButton(
    tags$h3("Download"),
    downloadButton(outputId = ns("dwnldBtn"),
                   label = ""),
    circle = TRUE,
    status = "default",
    icon = icon("download"),
    tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Download data"))
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do with a SVG image. Maybe it works with PNG, I didn't try. But SVG has better quality.

In the **www** folder, put your icon, say **myicon.svg**. Also put a CSS file, say **icon.css**, containing:

```css
.myicon::before {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: -.125em;
  content: url(./myicon.svg);
}
```

Then you can do:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(href="icon.css", rel="stylesheet")),
  downloadButton(
    "dwnld",
    icon = tags$i(class = "myicon")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For example, I take this icon:

[image]

Then I obtain:

[image]